# DataStructure's "DynamicArray" underperforms Association?

Tags: performance-tuning, data-structures

The documentation for DynamicArray states that it is *"An extensible array is useful for continuously appending elements, as well as for efficient element extraction and updating."*

I tried a test to see if a DynamicArray outperforms an Association:

```
testDA = CreateDataStructure["DynamicArray", Range[10^6]];
testAssoc = AssociationThread[Range[10^6], Range[10^6]];
```

Testing extraction:

```
RepeatedTiming[testDA["Part", 222]]
(*{6.82302*10^-7, 222}*)

RepeatedTiming[testAssoc[222]]
(*{1.28686*10^-7, 222}*)
```

Association is about 5 times faster for extraction.

Testing appending an element:

```
RepeatedTiming[testDA["Append", 1 + 10^6];]
(*{9.64685*10^-7, Null}*)

RepeatedTiming[AssociateTo[testAssoc, 1 + 10^6 -> 1 + 10^6];]
(*{1.18652*10^-6, Null}*)
```

Association is 1.2 times slower.

Testing changing an element:

```
RepeatedTiming[testDA["Part", 222] = 333;]
(*{6.59175*10^-7, Null}*)

  RepeatedTiming[testAssoc[222] = 333;]
    (*{6.93561*10^-7, Null}*)
```

Association is about 1.05 times slower.

Is this the wrong usage case for comparison?
If not, why would one use a "DynamicArray"?

*Addendum:
For flat lists, the timings are about the same except for AppendTo which is much slower--this has been discussed elsewhere on this forum.*

Comment: You seem to compare o(1) ops, still it is better to use different length. The timing results might be within statistical unsertanty, better to compute std too.

Comment: As for usage, docs for DA have application section. For association which is some sort of hash table, you need to store keys. New data structures seems to work with function compile.

Comment: @I.M. If the intended purpose of DataStructure is a type in FunctionCompile, that's great--but, wouldn't it be useful if the documentation for DataStructure included that in the Applications section?  I went down a rabbit hole with DynamicArray only to learn that it wasn't helping.

Comment: Which uses more memory?

Comment: @Edmund, I thought of checking but didn't.  It turns out that the `ByteCount@testAssoc` is 126MB and `ByteCount[testDA]` is 56 Bytes. I don't see how the  second case can possibly be that small.

Comment: @CraigCarter, be warned, `ByteCount` is implemented only for certain data structures, and will give wrong result for others (as commented during a [recent Live CEOing](https://youtu.be/dJdIV0v7Q-I?t=1168) – which might also be interesting to you in general).